# Pandas apply function to column then get attribute

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I'm trying to apply a function to a pandas column and then retrieve an attribute of function. To be specific, I'm using TextBlob to extract sentiment and polarity from a column of opinions.

Here's sample code I'm trying to run.

```
opinion = ['good', 'bad','horrible']
df = pd.DataFrame(opinion, columns=['comment'])
df.head()
    comment
0   good
1   bad
2   horrible
```

The pseudo-code I'm trying to run is

```
from textblob import TextBlob
df['sentiment'] = df.comment.apply(TextBlob).sentiment
```

Which raises AttributeError.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 df.comment.apply(TextBlob).sentiment

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5177             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5178                 return self[name]
-> 5179             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5180 
   5181     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'sentiment'
```

I was thinking of using `getattr()` function to this but it doesn't work.

```
df.comment.apply(TextBlob).apply(getattr,sentiment)
```

How can I apply a function and get attributes to a column?

Comment: `df['sentiment'] = df.comment.apply(TextBlob).sentiment` what is this supposed to mean? You're just defining the sentiment column, how do you intent to access it via `.sentiment` ?

Comment: probably you need `df.assign(sentiment = df.comment.apply(TextBlob)).sentiment`

Comment: Can you specify wwhere `TextBlob` comes from?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've added the package import statment above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Fast way of accessing a column of objects' attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455939/pandas-fast-way-of-accessing-a-column-of-objects-attribute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `attrgetter` here, which is a "curried" version of `getattr`:

```
from operator import attrgetter

df.comment.apply(TextBlob).apply(attrgetter('sentiment'))
```

In case `TextBlob` is however "vectorized", there might be a more effective way to calculate the sentiment of all the items, but at the moment, it is unclear how `TextBlob` is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a custom function that returns that value that you want.

```
def get_sentiment(x):
    _ = TextBlob(x)
    return _.sentiment

df['comment'].apply(get_sentiment)
```