# Accessing property of object stored in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
class Eq(object):
    price = 2

    # The class "constructor" - It's actually an initializer 
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.price = price

    def get_price():
        return price

d = {'name': ['cac40', 'ftse100'], 'col2': [Eq, Eq]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The above builds a Dataframe containing objects in `col2`,

I would like to access the price property of my objects, and put that in a new column of my dataframe.

I can't seem to be able to access the object though.

Closest I got is `df['price'] = df['col2'].values[0].price`, but of course this only gets the price property of the first row.

How can I get the price for all the rows?

Thanks

Comment: `df['price'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.price)`

Comment: That class is just an example, right? You wrote in a comment _This is the optimal way for me to store the objects (which I receive from an API)_, I'm curious to know why that's the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Fast way of accessing a column of objects' attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455939/pandas-fast-way-of-accessing-a-column-of-objects-attribute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, if you're trying to create a new column in a DataFrame and methods like this aren't working, it's not a bad idea to look for a way to use the "apply" function. You should be able to tackle your problem this way:

```
df['price'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.price)
```

Though this gets you what you want, why are you storing your object directly within the DataFrame? There might be a more optimal way to get data from your objects into it depending on your reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the optimal way for me to store the objects (which I receive from an API). An issue I am seeing now is that not all objects contain the property I'm looking for, so I'm thrown an 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error. Need to figure out how to fill the column with an empty char when the object doesn't have that property. Thanks for the help regardless :)

Comment: You can do the same thing with a conditional:

```
df['price'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.price if pd.notna(x.price) else <fill value>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of attribute values from a list of objects like this:

```
df['price'] = [obj.price for obj in df['col2']]
```